# facebook webhook error "select/poll on SSL socket, errno: 4"

Tags: facebook, hook

I get error log like this screenshot, I don't know what "select/poll on SSL socket, errno:4" error is and how to handle it. I googled but didn't find the answer. Anyone know please help, thanks.

[image]

Comment: I'm also getting same type error. But not too much.